# cp - Does not recognizning accent characters

Tags: bash, cp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have written a simple script, to copy some files, and change there name:

```
#!/bin/bash
for directory in ./../old_files/*; do
    DIR_NAME=$(basename $directory)
    for file in $directory/*; do
        filename=$(basename -- "$file")
        cp -- $file "./${DIR_NAME}_m*${filename}" 1>/dev/null
    done
done
```

And it's working great with one problem. If file has an accent or name is escaped with slash, it returns:
`cp: target 'xxx.pdf' is not a directory`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I also don't think your script works as well as you think it does.  `DIR_NAME` could potentially be set to a non-directory file, your `*` in the cp command is going to be taken literally.

Comment: if `directory` contains whitespace your script will break.

Comment: Have you considered using find?